# ActionView::Helpers::SanitizeHelper fails with multiple <wbr> tags

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sanitize

When html that is sanitized using the Rails ActionView::Helpers::SanitizeHelper it fails when there are multiple 'wbr' tags.

Text that has been pasted from other applications contains html that has literally hundreds of 'wbr' elements.

When the combined 'depth' of the 'wbr' elements and the outer elements in which they appear reaches 255 all further text in the document appears to be removed.

This can mean that important information is lost.

As an example if you run sanize on the fragment below:

```
<div>
  Some text here

  <wbr><wbr><wbr><wbr><wbr><wbr><wbr><wbr><wbr><wbr>
  <wbr><wbr><wbr><wbr><wbr><wbr><wbr><wbr><wbr><wbr>
  <wbr><wbr><wbr><wbr><wbr><wbr><wbr><wbr><wbr><wbr>
  <wbr><wbr><wbr><wbr><wbr><wbr><wbr><wbr><wbr><wbr>
  <wbr><wbr><wbr><wbr><wbr><wbr><wbr><wbr><wbr><wbr>
  <wbr><wbr><wbr><wbr><wbr><wbr><wbr><wbr><wbr><wbr>
  <wbr><wbr><wbr><wbr><wbr><wbr><wbr><wbr><wbr><wbr>
  <wbr><wbr><wbr><wbr><wbr><wbr><wbr><wbr><wbr><wbr>
  <wbr><wbr><wbr><wbr><wbr><wbr><wbr><wbr><wbr><wbr>
  <wbr><wbr><wbr><wbr><wbr><wbr><wbr><wbr><wbr><wbr>
  <wbr><wbr><wbr><wbr><wbr><wbr><wbr><wbr><wbr><wbr>
  <wbr><wbr><wbr><wbr><wbr><wbr><wbr><wbr><wbr><wbr>
  <wbr><wbr><wbr><wbr><wbr><wbr><wbr><wbr><wbr><wbr>
  <wbr><wbr><wbr><wbr><wbr><wbr><wbr><wbr><wbr><wbr>
  <wbr><wbr><wbr><wbr><wbr><wbr><wbr><wbr><wbr><wbr>
  <wbr><wbr><wbr><wbr><wbr><wbr><wbr><wbr><wbr><wbr>
  <wbr><wbr><wbr><wbr><wbr><wbr><wbr><wbr><wbr><wbr>
  <wbr><wbr><wbr><wbr><wbr><wbr><wbr><wbr><wbr><wbr>
  <wbr><wbr><wbr><wbr><wbr><wbr><wbr><wbr><wbr><wbr>
  <wbr><wbr><wbr><wbr><wbr><wbr><wbr><wbr><wbr><wbr>
  <wbr><wbr><wbr><wbr><wbr><wbr><wbr><wbr><wbr><wbr>
  <wbr><wbr><wbr><wbr><wbr><wbr><wbr><wbr><wbr><wbr>
  <wbr><wbr><wbr><wbr><wbr><wbr><wbr><wbr><wbr><wbr>
  <wbr><wbr><wbr><wbr><wbr><wbr><wbr><wbr><wbr><wbr>
  <wbr><wbr><wbr><wbr><wbr><wbr><wbr><wbr><wbr><wbr>
  <wbr><wbr><wbr><wbr><wbr>

  More important text here
</div>
```

The result does not contain the second piece of text. ie the result is:

```
<div>
  Some text here



</div>
```

I am looking for a way to safely sanitize the html that is pasted from other applications without losing any of the content.

I could obviously replace all 'wbr' elements with spaces using gsub prior to sanitizing but I would like to know that there are not other scenarios that will cause data loss in the same way.

Note that the Rails::Html::TargetScrubber has similar issues if you try to remove 'wbr' elements from the example segment then it removes the last text as well.

Comment: I think you should raise an issue in Rails [issue tracker](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues). Seems like a bug

Comment: @runyprince. Opened an issue [here](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/34442)

Comment: Hmm, looks like the bug is with Nokogiri (xml/html parsing gem) which Rails uses internally. The rabbit hole goes very deep.